# How can I use a relative path for a nodemailer attachment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemailer, html2pdf

I am using the html-pdf converter plugin to convert a HTML page to a PDF file. This plugin saves the PDF to the downloads folder.

I can attach a PDF to a nodemailer email like this:

```js
attachments: [{
    filename: 'transportpdf.pdf',
    path: '/Users/green/downloads/transportpdf.pdf',
    contentType: 'application/pdf'
}]
```

However, the path is static. Different users can have their download folder in different locations. Is there a way to mitigate this issue where I do not have to use a static file address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use : **[path.relative](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to)**

```
var relativePath = path.relative(process.cwd(), someFilePath);
```

Hope this helps.